# getUserMedia returns NotAllowedError the second time is used in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, permissions, getusermedia

We fail to understand why the second time we want to use a camera it fails giving NotAllowedError.
**We can use it once with no problem though.**
The first time, when it works, we are required to accept permissions and it works perfectly. The issue is that the permissions are prompted everytime it works, but the second time we require it, for example opening a new tab, it fails to work, and it does not prompt the permissions dialog.

**It only happens in iOS Chrome.**

It is fixed by closing the Chrome browser sometimes, others we need to restart the phone.

We are calling the stop tracks function before destroying the component, before requiring getUserMedia, and on `beforeunload` event:

```
stream.getTracks &&
  (await stream.getTracks().forEach((track: any) => {
    track.stop();
  }));
```

This is how we call user media:

```
export function getUserMedia(constraints?: MediaStreamConstraints | undefined) {
  return (
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) ||
    (navigator as any).getUserMedia(constraints) ||
    (navigator as any).webkitGetUserMedia(constraints) ||
    (navigator as any).mozGetUserMedia(constraints)
  );
}
```